# Shockwave motion with angle of attack

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, cfd

why is the shockwave picking in itself off the aerofoil with increasing deflection of the leading edge?

Angle of attack:3degrees
Aerofoil: naca0018
[image]

Comment: What is the source of these images, please?

Comment: didn't you mean to write "increasing deflection of the *trailing** edge"?